# Flutter 'The setter 'task= ' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, null

everyone!
I'm learning Flutter / Dart and keep having issues with instantiation and initialization.
Currently I'm writing a reorderable list but for some reason, I can't populate the list because my instance has some issue... (I think the issue is at these lines below)

```
List<String> tasks = [];
MyTask t;
tasks = [ t.task = 'Buy ice cream', t.task = 'Learn Flutter', t.task = 'Read books' ];)
```

Can you check it and give me a clue?
Thanks in advance. Any tip to seek docs is welcome!
Exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
The setter 'task=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: task="Buy ice cream"
```

Relevant code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './bottomNavigationBar.dart';
import './ViewFeed.dart';
import './ViewNewTodo.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //home: MyScaffold(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/':(context) => MyFeed(),
        '/toDo':(context) => MyScaffold(),
        '/newToDo':(context) => MyNewTodo(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My ToDoS'),
      ),
      body: MyReorderableTaskList(),
      floatingActionButton: MyFloatingActionButtonNewTodo() ,
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}

//Reorderable list elements
//FloatingActionButton
class MyFloatingActionButtonNewTodo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      tooltip: 'Idea',
      onPressed: ()=>{ Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/newToDo') },
    );
  }
}

class MyTask{
  String task;
  MyTask(this.task);
}
//ReorderableListView  implementation

class MyReorderableTaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyReorderableTaskListState createState() => _MyReorderableTaskListState();
}

class _MyReorderableTaskListState extends State<MyReorderableTaskList> {
  List<String> tasks = [];
  MyTask t;

  void initState(){
    tasks = [ t.task = 'Buy ice cream', t.task = 'Learn Flutter', t.task = 'Read books' ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: _onReorder,
        children: List.generate(
            tasks.length,
              (index){ return MyListView(index, Key('$index'), tasks ); }
              ),
          );
  }
  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex){
    setState(() {
        if(newIndex > oldIndex) { newIndex -= 1; }
        final String item = tasks.removeAt(oldIndex);
        tasks.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }
}

class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final Key key;
  final List<String> listTasks;
  MyListView(this.index, this.key, this.listTasks);
  @override
  _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blue,
            onTap: ()=>{ MaterialState.focused },
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Tarea: ${widget.listTasks[widget.index]} | ${widget.index}',),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyTask t;` is null. `t` isn't actually anything yet. You must create a new object `MyTask()` and assign it to `t`

Change it to

```
MyTask t = new MyTask("");
```

Edit: More thorough explanation

You can't just declare `MyTask t;` and then try to use `t`, because you have not yet said what `t` is. That's like declaring `int a;` and then trying to do `print(a + 5)`. You can't do that, because you have not yet assigned a value to `a`. Similarly, `MyTask t;` means you have created a variable *named* `t` of *type* `MyTask`. In other words, you have *declared* a variable `t`. But you must still *initialize* it, in other words, assign `t` a value of type `MyTask`, otherwise the value of `t` will be `null`.

So to summarize,

```
MyTask t;
t.task = "Hello";
```

will not work, because it's like doing

```
int a;
int b = a + 5;
```

You can't add 5 to a, because although you have declared the variable `a`, you have not yet initialized it, so it does not yet have a value.

Likewise, you can't access the `.task` property of `t`, because you haven't said what `t` is. `t` is just `null`.

So you must initialize `t` by instantiating a new `MyTask` object-

`MyTask t = new MyTask("");`

The `""` is required inside the parentheses because your MyTask class constructor requires a parameter.

```
class MyTask{
  String task;
  MyTask(this.task); // Parameter required to assign to the String task
}
```

[This might help you.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_classes.htm)

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you very much! But earlier the former ```MyTask t;``` run without a problem. Is there a 'correct' instantiation recommended for a particular circumstances?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would have worked for you before. I edited my answer to provide an explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I messed a lot the code and things start broke at some point. I will try to read docs more carefully and back to basics. I started coding in JS and PHP and the C#, Java like languages (like Dart) are a hard trip sometimes.

Comment: No problem. And yes, languages like C#, Java, and Dart are called class-based object-orientated languages, and they're a different beast from JS and PHP. But once you wrap your head around the basics, it's no problem. If you're new to these languages, take my advice and do some Java tutorials. Learn the basics of Java, and once you feel comfortable you'll be able to switch to Dart easily with no problems. I suggest Java because there are a lot more resources to help you learn Java. Good luck.

Comment: Thanksyou for the advice and time. I'm   very excited about Flutter, but the time i

Comment: I'm struggle with the basic it's frustrating. I'll take a break and revise 101.